# HeatMap cell Transparent or none

Tags: javascript, highcharts, heatmap

While plotting HeatMap it displays empty space (i.e. white cell) where data point doesn't exist, how can i make it transparent? similar to this
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29660084/no-gaps-in-heatmap)

Comment: How your data looks like, can you try to put null value for point which is "transparent" ?

Comment: i'm getting data from SQL query, when there is no data/record for a particular cell it is showing white box/cell. As u said i can't put null, because i don't have {x,y} values from the query, if query is fetching {x,y} then i can put "null" and it would work.. in this case complete record of {x,y,value} is missing.

Comment: In this fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/4to2xfL1/3/) it is working. But when i'm using in jasper it is showing that white block in this way [image link](http://ibin.co/206U7mr4uaxN)

Comment: You need to load your data and then parse it to push missing points. Then use in highcharts. Could you paste exampel of json from jasper?